# Can't seem to capture newline+spaces in Regex

Tags: regex

I know regexes aren't the best for web parsing, but I'm using it as an exercise.

I'm using `Район:[^<>]*\n\s*<[^<>]*>\n\s*<a[^<>]*>([^<>]+)<\/a>`

to try to match:

```
Район: </span>
                <span class="company__contacts-item-text">
                    <a class="link" href="/moscow/top/marina-roscha/">Марьина роща</a>
```

I've been looking at it for a while but I don't know what I've been doing wrong. How can I capture something that would have newlines and different urls in the tags?

Comment: Like: https://regex101.com/r/oI7gN6/1 ?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
Район:.+?<a[^>]+>(.+?)</a>
```

**DESCRIPTION**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/wA4oH0/1